# How to reorder the node of sankey plot to go from large to small without altering the colour

Tags: r, ggplot2, sankey-diagram

I'm not sure if this is possible but I was hoping to reorder how my first level of nodes get displayed in my sankey plot so that the it starts with the largest box to the smallest box without altering the order of the `viridis scale`. here is a sample of my dataframe

```
df = structure(list(x = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
                                    1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
                                    1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
                                    1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), levels = c("Method_Group", 
                                                                                        "Topic"), class = "factor"), node = c("Receiver + Mobile", "Behavioural Ecology", 
                                                                                                                              "Receiver + Mobile", "Conservation Measures", "No Receiver + Animal-borne", 
                                                                                                                              "Other Drivers", "Receiver + Stationary", "Behavioural Ecology", 
                                                                                                                              "Receiver + Stationary", "Behavioural Ecology", "Receiver + Stationary", 
                                                                                                                              "Reproductive Ecology", "Receiver + Stationary", "Other Drivers", 
                                                                                                                              "Receiver + Stationary", "Behavioural Ecology", "Receiver + Stationary", 
                                                                                                                              "Methodological", "Receiver + Baited", "Behavioural Ecology", 
                                                                                                                              "Receiver + Baited", "Methodological", "Receiver + Baited", "Reproductive Ecology", 
                                                                                                                              "Receiver + Baited", "Landuse Management", "No Receiver + Animal-borne", 
                                                                                                                              "Other Drivers", "No Receiver + Animal-borne", "Behavioural Ecology", 
                                                                                                                              "No Receiver + Animal-borne", "Methodological", "No Receiver + Animal-borne", 
                                                                                                                              "Reproductive Ecology", "No Receiver + Animal-borne", "Behavioural Ecology", 
                                                                                                                              "No Receiver + Animal-borne", "Fisheries Management", "No Receiver + Animal-borne", 
                                                                                                                              "Behavioural Ecology", "No Receiver + Animal-borne", "Methodological", 
                                                                                                                              "No Receiver + Animal-borne", "Fisheries Management", "Receiver + Stationary", 
                                                                                                                              "Behavioural Ecology", "No Receiver + Animal-borne", "Methodological", 
                                                                                                                              "No Receiver + Animal-borne", "Conservation Measures"), next_x = structure(c(2L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                           NA, 2L, NA, 2L, NA, 2L, NA, 2L, NA, 2L, NA, 2L, NA, 2L, NA, 2L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                           NA, 2L, NA, 2L, NA, 2L, NA, 2L, NA, 2L, NA, 2L, NA, 2L, NA, 2L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                           NA, 2L, NA, 2L, NA, 2L, NA, 2L, NA, 2L, NA, 2L, NA, 2L, NA, 2L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                           NA), levels = c("Method_Group", "Topic"), class = "factor"), 
                    next_node = c("Behavioural Ecology", NA, "Conservation Measures", 
                                  NA, "Other Drivers", NA, "Behavioural Ecology", NA, "Behavioural Ecology", 
                                  NA, "Reproductive Ecology", NA, "Other Drivers", NA, "Behavioural Ecology", 
                                  NA, "Methodological", NA, "Behavioural Ecology", NA, "Methodological", 
                                  NA, "Reproductive Ecology", NA, "Landuse Management", NA, 
                                  "Other Drivers", NA, "Behavioural Ecology", NA, "Methodological", 
                                  NA, "Reproductive Ecology", NA, "Behavioural Ecology", NA, 
                                  "Fisheries Management", NA, "Behavioural Ecology", NA, "Methodological", 
                                  NA, "Fisheries Management", NA, "Behavioural Ecology", NA, 
                                  "Methodological", NA, "Conservation Measures", NA)), class = c("rowwise_df", 
                                                                                                 "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -50L), groups = structure(list(
                                                                                                   .rows = structure(list(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 
                                                                                                                          10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 
                                                                                                                          21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 
                                                                                                                          32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 
                                                                                                                          43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 50L), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                 "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, -50L), class = c("tbl_df", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             "tbl", "data.frame")))
```

and this is the code I am using to reorder from most to least (largest box to smallest box)

```
df$node <- factor(
  df$node,
  levels =
    c("Receiver + Baited","Receiver + Mobile","Receiver + Stationary",
      "No Receiver + Animal-borne",
      "Behavioural Ecology", 
      "Conservation Measures","Methodological","Other Drivers", 
      "Reproductive Ecology", "Fisheries Management", "Landuse Management"))
```

And here is the code I am using to graph it

```
library(ggsankey)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

width <- .4

p <- ggplot(df, aes(x = x, next_x = next_x, node = node, next_node = next_node, fill = factor(node), label = node)) +
  geom_sankey(flow.alpha = 1, node.color = "black", show.legend = FALSE, width = width) +
  theme_void() +
  theme(
    plot.margin = unit(rep(5.5, 4), "pt")
  ) +
  scale_fill_viridis_d()

# Get the data from the flows layer
dat <- layer_data(last_plot(), 1) |>
  filter(x == 2 - width / 2) |>
  distinct(fill, flow_end_ymax, .keep_all = TRUE)

p = p +
  geom_rect(data = dat, aes(
    xmin = x, xmax = x + width,
    ymin = flow_end_ymin, ymax = flow_end_ymax,
    fill = label
  ), inherit.aes = FALSE) +
  geom_sankey_label(size = 5, color = "black", fill = "white") +
  guides(fill = "none")



p
```

When I graph it I get something that looks like this[image]

Which as you can see the colours don't follow the standard light to dark format of `viridis scale`. Any ideas how to fix this

Answer (score 1):

As you didn't provide the code I don't know what you tried with `factor` and why this does not work for your. But basically you are right. In 99% of all questions related to orderings the answer is to convert to a `factor` which also works for your case:

```r
library(ggsankey)
library(dplyr, warn = FALSE)
library(ggplot2)

df$node <- factor(
  df$node,
  levels =
    c(
      "stationary-receiver", "baited-receiver",
      "mobile-receiver", "animal-borne-no-receiver",
      "Other Drivers", "Reproductive Ecology",
      "Methodological", "Behavioural Ecology",
      "Conservation Measures"
    )
)

width <- .4

p <- ggplot(df, aes(x = x, next_x = next_x, node = node, next_node = next_node, fill = factor(node), label = node)) +
  geom_sankey(flow.alpha = 1, node.color = "black", show.legend = FALSE, width = width) +
  theme_void() +
  theme(
    plot.margin = unit(rep(5.5, 4), "pt")
  ) +
  scale_fill_viridis_d()

# Get the data from the flows layer
dat <- layer_data(last_plot(), 1) |>
  filter(x == 2 - width / 2) |>
  distinct(fill, flow_end_ymax, .keep_all = TRUE)

p <- p +
  geom_rect(data = dat, aes(
    xmin = x, xmax = x + width,
    ymin = flow_end_ymin, ymax = flow_end_ymax,
    fill = label
  ), inherit.aes = FALSE) +
  geom_sankey_label(size = 5, color = "black", fill = "white") +
  guides(fill = "none")

p
```

[image]

**EDIT** With the new data and code:

```r
library(ggsankey)
library(ggplot2)

width <- .4

p <- ggplot(df, aes(
  x = x, next_x = next_x, node = node, next_node = next_node,
  fill = factor(node), label = node
)) +
  geom_sankey(
    flow.alpha = 1, node.color = "black",
    show.legend = FALSE, width = width
  ) +
  theme_void() +
  theme(
    plot.margin = unit(rep(5.5, 4), "pt")
  ) +
  scale_fill_viridis_d()

# Get the data from the flows layer
dat <- layer_data(last_plot(), 1) |>
  dplyr::filter(x == 2 - width / 2) |>
  dplyr::distinct(fill, flow_end_ymax, .keep_all = TRUE)

p <- p +
  geom_rect(data = dat, aes(
    xmin = x, xmax = x + width,
    ymin = flow_end_ymin, ymax = flow_end_ymax,
    fill = label
  ), inherit.aes = FALSE) +
  geom_sankey_label(size = 5, color = "black", fill = "white") +
  guides(fill = "none")
p
```

[image]

Comment: Interesting, Ok it is now working but strangely when I use the ```factor``` code the colours also change order. So unlike yours, my ```viridis``` scale does not go from light to dark anymore. Any idea why mine might be doing that?

Comment: Hm. Can't reproduce. I got the same colors with the code and new data you added (see my edit). To check., I'm using `packageVersion("ggplot2")`3.4.4 and `packageVersion("ggsankey")` 0.0.99999. And of course: Try with restarting your R session. BTW: As a general rule please do not change the data and code from your original question as this makes answers useless. Add changes as an edit.

Comment: Yes I am using all the same. Sorry about the edit. I have no idea why the colours are not working. Even when I use this reproducible example here it still happens to me.